# Ubuntu Server 18.04 EXT4-fs error

Tags: boot, server, ext4

So about a couple of weeks ago, I decided I wanted to make a server computer (on my laptop) and well run servers on it. I thought best option would be to pick Ubuntu Server. When I went to the website it gave me the latest version 18.04. Anyways I was able to install it successfully but after 5 minutes of it being booted up, instant EXT4-fs error. Apparently the issue just disappeared for a bit until I was running the server for about 3 days in a row (I did restart it somewhere in the middle of those 3 days) when suddenly I was just running a Minecraft Server and it just had a bunch of errors. None of them showed up saying EXT4-fs error but I can't remember what it said. So I do the logical thing and Reboot it. I rebooted it and I get a bunch of Failed things on the boot up and then it did some sort of disk check maybe? Can't quite remember. Anyways after it was done, it didn't solve the problem. I just got more EXT4-fs errors. Anyway to solve this? And do I have to reset the Operating System? Resetting won't do too much because I have a backup of everything which is fairly recent. Also sorry if I did anything wrong because this is my first post.

Thanks.

-Mike M

Comment: Can you add the actual error messages to your question? Without that there is not much anyone can do to help you.

Comment: Well the issue with that is I can't copy and paste it and all the text goes too fast. Is there any log files on there?

Comment: I think I solved it. I just used 'sudo touch /forcefsck' and I haven't gotten errors since.